# Django3 prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-3.0

I had worked by django 2.X. But I'm going to use django3.x at my new project.
At version2, when I should make outer join. I used `prefetch_related` and filtered about model of `prefetch_related`.

In version 2, if I use `prefetch_related` it was queried as single query. but in version 3, queried by multiple query.

If I only use Q() of joined target without `prefetch_related`, it works single query at version 3.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class Member(models.Model):
    member_no = models.AutoField()
    member_name = models.CharField()


class Permission(models.Model):
    permission_no = models.AutoField()


class MemberPermission(models.Model):
    member_permission_no = models.AutoField()
    member_no = models.ForeignKey(
        Member, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    permission_no = models.ForeignKey(
        Permission, related_name='member_permissions', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )


my_permission = Member.objects.prefetch_related('member_permissions').filter(Q(member_permissions__isnull=False))[:1]
print(my_permission[0].member_permissions)  
# member outer join permission, single query at django 2.X
# member outer join permission & additional query at django 3.x

my_permission = Member.objects.filter(Q(member_permissions__isnull=False))[:1]
print(my_permission[0].member_permissions)  
# member outer join permission, single query at django 3.X

my_permission = Member.objects.prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('member_permissions', MemberPermission.objects.select_related(
                        'permission_no').all())
                ).filter(Q(members__isnull=False))[:1]
print(my_permission[0].member_permissions.all()[0].permission_no.permission_no)
# member outer join permission & additional query at django 3.x
```

If I don't use `prefetch_related`, I could get single query.

But if I want to get model of joined model (Permission of MemberPermission by Member) it couldn't.

I wonder how to query once by `Prefetch()` in django3.

Comment: How did you determine this is caused by the version difference? Did you create a test that counts the number of queries, then run it in 2 different virtual envs (using [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for example) to show the issue?

Comment: @Melvyn I'm sorry i make mistake. I have tried again by venvs as your comment. It was executed as same not different.  If I use '''prefetch_related'''  and try to fetch columns, always executes multiple query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a version difference. It's the way `prefetch_related` works. It will execute 1 extra query per outer join. However, this is still a *lot* less than executing 1 query per iteration. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is very clear on this:

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related.

So let's say we have a 2 outer joins and in total 1000 matching rows:

- Number of queries without prefetch_related: 1 + 2*1000 = 2001
- Number of queries with prefetch_related: 1 + 2 = 3

So it makes very little sense to worry about that 1 extra query per join.